# Get declared fields of projection interface

Tags: spring-data, field, projection

I would get all fields set in projections interfaces. When I use getDeclaredFields on a class it's ok, but on projection interface return an empty list.
Do you know a way to get them?

Answer (score 0):

The interface itself doesn't have any fields because it's basically a thing that declares for you some possibillity, i.e. *what can be done using it*, so there is no any info about fields. But you can use `intrf.getClass().getInterfaces()` instead to take a list of interfaces related to your object. Then iterate through it and invoke a `getDeclaredMethods()` for a desired interface

Comment: Thanks for your answer was really usefull!

Comment: you are welcome) please upvote the answer and accept it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers